# Error de Kivy en VisualStudio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, vscode, kivy

Instale el Kivy en windows tal y como indica el tutorial de la pagina, y una vez que creo este codigo en visual studio code:

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="KIVY")

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

me aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy
```

Y no se como arreglarlo, busco en Google y en foros y nada.

Comment: Cuando pasa ésto si la instalación fue bien, en el 99% de los casos se debe a  que el IDE está usando un intérprete o entorno virtual diferente al que instalase Kivy.

Comment: Como puedo ver eso en visual studio code?

Comment: Mírate https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment. En cuanto a instaalar, no se si usaste conda o instalaste en un intérprete con PIP directamente y con que  comando exactamente, dependiendo del caso el interprete en el que verdaderamente instalaste variará.

Comment: Instale con pip

Comment: Que interprete deberia correr el kivy?

Comment: Ahí me funciono! muchísimas gracias

Answer (score -1):

En Vscode, abre desde ahí en la parte inferior derecha con el <kbd>+↓</kbd> CMD(Command prompt) y escribe

```
pip freeze
```

en el terminal.

revisa si en esta lista esta kivy, y si no es así entonces desde ahí corre

```
pip install kivy
```

o si no hazlo directamente.

Y luego trata de nuevo.

Tambien puedes probar actualizando tu version de Python